# Call C++ class method in a C function on same project

Tags: c++, c, qt

i have a Qt Gui project that formed mixed-language with C and C++. I must use a C++ class function in my C source. How to call it? Can u help me?

C++ function to call

```
 void MainWindow::putsDisplay(int Line, char *string)
{
    if(Line == 0)
    {
        ui->customerLine_1->setPlainText(string);
    }

    if(Line == 1)
    {
        ui->customerLine_2->setPlainText(string);
    }

    if(Line == 2)
    {
        ui->cashierLine_1->setPlainText(string);
    }

    if(Line == 3)
    {
        ui->cashierLine_2->setPlainText(string);
    }

    if(Line == 4)
    {
        ui->printerArea->setPlainText(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a C++ method directly, you have to create a function in order to call your object's method. Here is an example (part of a C++ file):

```
extern C 
{

    void   example(int Line, char *string)
    {
       static MainWindow win;

       win.putsDisplay(Line, string); 
    }

}
```

C code:

```
int main()
{
    example(42, "it is an example");
    return 0;
}
```

`extern C` will disabled name mangling, so `example()` can be called from C code. You can keep `static MainWindow win;`, or made it global or whatever, but you will need an `MainWindow` object.

Comment: i have already an instance in MainWindow obj. So no need new instance, when i call the function in main.c, i need to sth to specify this instance, sth like that wrapper or ...

Comment: You can use my solution (which is a wrapper actually), you just have to access to your instance from `example()`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, C is a subset of C++.

You can name the file that has the C code as x.C or x.cpp and compile it with the rest of the files with c++ compiler.  Then you will be able to call the C++ method from the C code.

Comment: i prefer saying: C++ is a Superset of C... :(